# How to Automatically Click Hyperlinks in a Web Page?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, ui-automation

There is a page with hundreds of hyperlinks, each hyperlink is displayed as a text "Download" as follows:

```
Download
Download
Download
```

Now we need to download all the scripts, but as you can see, there are many hyperlinks, and it will cost lots of time to click each hyperlink and then save the file one by one.

So we wonder if there is a quick way to download all the files, maybe using web-automation? 
Do you have any suggestion or recommendation about the tools?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you made any attempts of your own, or done any research? I'm sure if you did a quick look for "Click links using JavaScript" or something along those lines, you'd find a trove of helpful documentation. In the meantime, please take a minute to familiarize with [**how to ask**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Best of luck!

Answer (score -1):

Use the extension downthemall  on firefox https://www.downthemall.net/
this has what you need

please research more

Comment: Hi, the "downthemall " add-on is not compatible with the latest Firefox version 61.0.2(Firefox Quantum ). Anyway, thanks for the information :)

Comment: you could downgrade firefox and install it

Comment: here you can download a previous version of firefox i think v50 would work https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/